# getting HttpBasic form even though I disabled it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is my Security config where I disable HttpBasic and FormLogin but yet I get generated password..How Can I disable it and following up the logic?

could be a problem that my dependencies wrong?

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserAuthenticationEntryPoint userAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling((exceptionalHandling) -> exceptionalHandling.accessDeniedPage("/errors/access-denied"))
                .authenticationProvider((AuthenticationProvider) userAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(userAuthenticationProvider), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement((sessionManagement) -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login", "/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/message").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

and this is the entryPoint Auth

```
@Component
public class UserAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void commence(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), new ErrorDto("Unauthorized path"));
    }
}
```

Here is the AuthProvider

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component

public class UserAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Value("${security.jwt.token.secret-key:secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        // this is to avoid having the raw secret key available in the JVM
        secretKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getBytes());
    }

    public String createToken(String login) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + 3600000); // 1 hour

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey);
        return JWT.create()
                .withIssuer(login)
                .withIssuedAt(now)
                .withExpiresAt(validity)
                .sign(algorithm);
    }

    public Authentication validateToken(String token) {
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey);

        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                .build();

        DecodedJWT decoded = verifier.verify(token);

        UserDto user = userService.findByLogin(decoded.getIssuer());

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, Collections.emptyList());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.entur.jwt-rs:jwt-spring-auth0:1.1.16'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and here is my application properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
server.port=8080
security.basic.enable=false
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController

public class AuthController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthProvider;
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> login (@RequestBody CredentialsDto credentialsDto) {
        UserDto user = userService.login(credentialsDto);
        user.setToken(userAuthProvider.createToken(user.getLogin()));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> register(@RequestBody SignUpDto signUpDto) {
        UserDto user = userService.register(signUpDto);
        user.setToken(userAuthProvider.createToken(user.getLogin()));
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/users/" + user.getId()))
                .body(user);
    }
}
```

So I want remove HttpBasic and auth by jwt

Comment: Disabling basic and form login have nothing to do with generating a user. You don't have a `UserDetailsService` and Spring Boot will automatically create an in memory one with a generated user.